# How to autonomously trigger transactions from Node.js?

Tags: transactions, parity, javascript, nodejs, raspberry-pi

I have a a JS file running on NodeJS on multiple devices which interact to each other, trying to write data on the Blockchain and send transactions.
The problem is that every time I have to manually insert the password. I have been using personal.unlockAccount in the client console but this doesn't really solve the situation...

I am trying to develop a micro-electricity-market where multiple autonomous transactions are sent every 15 minutes, I can't stay in front of the screen all the time.

Is there any way to achieve what i would like to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about Parity, but Go-Ethereu `unlockAccount` takes a second argument that is time how long it keeps the account unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `personal` API enabled on your node, you can interact with it with web3 just like you would via the console.

If I'm automating something, I generally configure the service to run as an isolated user on my system.  Then, I'll put the password for the account the user interacts with in a file in the user's home directory (or other location), and change the permissions to be readable only by that user.

Then I'll use a wrapper like the following to allow me to easily unlock an account, send a transaction (or set of transactions), and then re-lock the account:

```
function whileUnlocked(web3, account, pwfile, task) {
  return readFile(pwfile, 'utf8')
    .then(function(pw) {
      return web3.personal.unlockAccount(account, pw.trim())
        .then(task)
        .then(function() {
          return web3.personal.lockAccount(account)
        });
    });
}
```

Note that this requires a modified version of web3 that's been extended to use Promises, since it simplifies this flow.

This could probably be improved by making the final `then` a `finally`, to always lock the account, regardless of whether or not the task fails.

The important bits for your uses: you'd want to call `web3.personal.unlockAccount`, pass it a callback that does whatever you need to do while the transaction is unlocked, then call `web3.personal.lockAccount` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

We have used in the pass ConsenSys' hooked-web3-provider (It is now deprecated, they point to a similar project https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs-provider-signer). That way we have a service which will sign transactions without exposing the privatekey, for example we can have a hardware key.

Our problem with `personal.unlockAccount` is while your account is unlocked in your node can sign **any** transaction. So you have a tiny window of time where your node can be attacked by a malicious third party.